# Ranking two pages for same keyword on different domains at google

Tags: seo, google, domains

what is it like to rank two pages, with different domains and IP's, for the identical keyword, with different content, on Google? The two pages have the same owner. Does Google recognize that the two pages have the same owner and according to that, lists only one of the two pages and penalizes the other one? What if both pages are on the same IP. Is it favorable to take different IP's? What else do I have to consider?

The goal is to rank two pages from two domains in Top 10 or Top 20. Does Google penalize this if it is detected that the owner is the same, or not?

Our problem is that we can't get our main site ranked for the keyword, because the landing page already ranks for the keyword.

Does anyone have any idea about my problem?

Answer (score 2):

When I was starting out in SEO we had ten out of ten spots for a plumber search in a major metro. Honestly, I don't remember how we did it, and none of the stuff we did there would work now.

I am a little confused by your question. The entire point of a landing page is to rank for that keyword, deliver content, convert, more efficiently than the home page. Home page is for branded search more than keywords. What do your users do on the home page that they can't on the landing page?

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. The point is for me, whether google penalizes a company, when it has two sites on different domains for the same keyword, so its harder to rank both of them, or is this not the real problem. I would be happy if there is a clear answer for this question.

What do your users do on the home page that they can't on the landing page? 
>There is no added value on homepage, just the goal to rank two pages as far up as possible.